# Remove string after second comma Oracle / PL SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have this value '45465,6464,654'  And I want to remove second comma and string after it. So basically I want ''45465,6464' . I found a solution but its for Mssql. How can I make this query for Oracle I couldnt do it even with substring. Can you help me?

This for MSSQL;

`declare @S varchar(20) = '45465@6464@654';

select left(@S, charindex('@', @S, charindex('@', @S)+1)-1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something very similar:

```sql
WITH s AS (SELECT '45465@6464@654' s FROM dual)
SELECT SUBSTR(s,1,INSTR(s,'@',1,2)-1) FROM s
```

or you can use regular Expression:

```sql
SELECT regexp_substr('45465@6464@654','([^@]*@)?[^@]*') from dual
```

Comment: Thank you much Radagast81 :) It helped.